# How to start processes sequentially through code

Tags: c#, process

I have to run 3 processes sequentially, one after other. The second process must start after first process' completion. 
I work in C#. I have used Process.Start() method, Where it kicks on all at same time.
Can anyone help me.

Comment: Please post your current code and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Process.Start("yourprogram.exe").WaitForExit();
Process.Start("yournextprogram.exe").WaitForExit();
```

and so on...

Comment: the same problem as with @Sebastian's answer applies here: This will block all user input, which is probably not what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @codesparkle I answered the question the OP asked, why downvote when you don't know any more details than anyone else does? Your method might work as well but unless we have more details there is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: the problem is that the above scenario will be undesirable __in just about every use case__ I can think of. Even if it *were* a console application, he would probably want to display *some* status information while he is running the processes.

Comment: Ok, but I still think downvotes should be reserved for unhelpful answers, this does what the OP asked...

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing it adding a handler for the [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event of the first process, and then starting the second process from there.

```
void StartProcessOne() {
    Process p = Process.Start("foo", "bar");
    p.Exited += (sender, e) => StartProcessTwo();
    p.Start();
}

void StartProcessTwo() {
    Process p = Process.Start("foo2", "bar2");
    p.Exited += (sender, e) => StartProcessThree();
    p.Start();
}

...
```

You can also use the [`WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) method, which waits for the process to end before continuing execution of your code. Note, however, this makes your own process stop execution until the other process terminates. This can leave you with an unresponsive user interface and such, which can be quite undesirable.<sup>([source](http://goo.gl/4mS2i))</sup>

Comment: It should be used with some attention to UI-Application processes, in some cases process exit could be skipped, se Remarks part on MSDN

Comment: this approach is not advisable if he has a user interface (which I strongly suspect), because it will block all user input, according to MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by responding to the Process.Exited event.
**You should use this approach instead of WaitForExit() because the latter will block your program from responding to user input, etc...**

```
private int n = 0;

private void StartAProcess()
{
    Process process = new Process {
        StartInfo = {FileName = "cmd.exe", Arguments = "pause"}, 
        EnableRaisingEvents = true};
    process.Exited += process_Exited;
    process.Start();
    n++;
}

void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (n < 3) StartAProcess();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code for each process

```
Process.WaitForExit()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326953(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4 you could use the System.Threading.Tasks API.  If your graph gets more complex you may get some mileage from http://pdag.codeplex.com (I must confess, this is my work).

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a process.join() to wait for the first process to complete before submitting the next one. However, the bigger question is why you are using Process.Start() - for asynchronous tasks - when you actually want them to run synchronously? Just calling:

```
a();
b();
c();
```

will run them one after another.

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process` does __NOT__ have a `Join()` method.

Comment: OK - WaitForExit instead. I should have checked.